# Change divs through onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have some code that looks like so;

```
<div id="welcome">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Welcome</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Hi, would you like to sign up or keep watching?</p>
        <button id="intro_signup_button" type="text" onclick="**HERE**">SIGN UP</button>
        <button id="intro_back_button" type="text" onclick="document.getElementById('welcome').style.display='none'">KEEP WATCHING</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="signup">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <p>texttextext</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when I click the sign up button, I want the div to change to the signup div below, but using the same coding type (if possible) that I used for closing the window. I know it's obvious that I'm a beginner, but I've been searching everywhere and playing around with different techniques but I just can't figure it out!

Comment: which is "the div" you wanted to change? You can try using display none/block attributes.

Comment: @Coderchu If you read the question you'll know =>  "I want the div to change to the `signup` div below"

Answer (score 1):

Really as simple as this:

```css
#signup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Welcome</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Hi, would you like to sign up or keep watching?</p>
    <button id="intro_signup_button" type="text" onclick="document.getElementById('signup').style.display='block';">SIGN UP</button>
    <button id="intro_back_button" type="text" onclick="document.getElementById('welcome').style.display='none';">KEEP WATCHING</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="signup">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p>texttextext</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

And if you want a version that hides the Welcome layer before show the Signup layer:

```css
#signup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Welcome</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Hi, would you like to sign up or keep watching?</p>
    <button id="intro_signup_button" type="text" onclick="document.getElementById('signup').style.display='block';document.getElementById('welcome').style.display='none'">SIGN UP</button>
    <button id="intro_back_button" type="text" onclick="document.getElementById('welcome').style.display='none';">KEEP WATCHING</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="signup">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p>texttextext</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to upvote and check this answer as the correct answer. Thank you and see you soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery :

```
$("#intro_signup_button").click(function() {
  $("#signup").show();
});

$("#intro_back_button").click(function() {
  $("#signup").hide();
});
```

```js
$("#intro_signup_button").click(function() {
  $("#signup").show();
});

$("#intro_back_button").click(function() {
  $("#signup").hide();
});
```

```css
#signup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcome">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Welcome</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Hi, would you like to sign up or keep watching?</p>
    <button id="intro_signup_button">SIGN UP</button>
    <button id="intro_back_button">KEEP WATCHING</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="signup">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p>show sign up</p>
  </div>
</div>
```